# How to add rows on a JTable using AbstractTableModel?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable with my own Model (extends AbstractTableModel), and I'd like to add a row to it when I Click a JButton.

I don't really know how to hadd the row to the Model.

here is my model:

```
public class MembersModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  String[] columnNames = {
    "Name",
    "Money Spent",
    "Percent",
    "Current Deck"
  };

  Object[][] data = {
  {"Cajo", new Integer(150), new Integer(0), "Event Deck"},
  {"Sekiam", new Integer(200), new Integer(0), "Jeskay"},
  {"Nuvas", new Integer(100), new Integer(0), "Big Shit"},
  {"Dos", new Integer(100), new Integer(0), "Crap Deck"},
  {"Atoj", new Integer(100), new Integer(0), "IDK"}
  };

  public MembersModel(){
      super();
      calcAllPercent();
  }

  public void calcAllPercent(){
      for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        data[i][2] = calcPercetage((Integer) data[i][1]);
      }
  }

  private int calcPercetage(int money){
      return (money*100)/teamMoneySpent();
  }

  private int teamMoneySpent(){
      int money = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i){
        money += (Integer) data[i][1];
      }
      return money;
   }

    public int getColumnCount() {
       return columnNames.length;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
       return data.length;
    }

    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col];
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return data[row][col];
    }

    public Class getColumnClass(int c) {
        return getValueAt(0, c).getClass();
    }

    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
       return false;
    } 

    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        data[row][col] = value;
        calcAllPercent();
        fireTableRowsUpdated(0, 4);
    }
}
```

Should i create my table aswell or add the method to the Model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key will be the data nucleus that you're using for your model, which here is your 2-D array, `Object[][] data`. The question then boils down to this: how do you add another row to the array and then notify the model's listener of the addition. While this **can** be done by creating a new data array with another row, copying all the data from this array, and adding the new data to the newly added row, why bother? For my money I'd

- create a class to hold the data of a single table row, here I'll call it `MyType`, but you'll give it a better name, and it will have String, int, int, and String fields to correspond to the columns of your table.
- Give this class some of the methods you have in your model above, such as doing row-specific calculations, `calcPercentage(..)`, `teamMoneySpent(...)`, and then the model can call the row object's method when this information is needed.
- use an `ArrayList<MyType>` as my table model data nucleus, **not** a 2-dimensional hard-coded array.
- give my model class an `addRow(MyType myObj)` method
- in the method add to the ArrayList
- and then call the appropriate model notification method, which here would be `fireTableRowsInserted(...)`.

---

Note, I'm not sure what you mean by,

> Should i create my table aswell or add the method to the Model?

Comment: by



`Should i create my table aswell or add the method to the Model?`

Should i create my table aswell or add the method to the Model?
I meant create a type that extends JTable.

I got your process, thanks for the help

Comment: @CarlosMorgado: you may need to extend JTable for other reasons, but it has nothing to do with the crux of your current question.

Answer (score 3):

Some problems with your current model:

1. The `setValueAt()` method is wrong. You should invoking `tableCellUpdated(...)`. You don't want to repaint the data in the entire table when you update a single cell. Actually you don't even need to implement the `setValueAt(...)` method because your table is not editable.
2. You didn't override the `getColumnClass(...)` method. This method is required so the table can use the proper renderer to display the data.

Instead of creating a completely new TableModel, you could extend the `DefaultTableModel`. It already supports an `addRow(...)` method.

However, as hovercraft has already pointed out a better design is create a custom Object to store all the data of a single row. For a solution that uses this approach check out [Row Table Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/21/row-table-model/) for a solution. The base TableModel is more complicated, but it makes it easier to create custom TableModels in the future since all the common code is in one class.

I would implement hovercraft's suggestion first so you better understand the concepts of creating a TableModel with a custom Object. I include this link as a suggestion for the future.